# Question regarding the finale of White Collar

Tags: white-collar

At the very end of [White Collar](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1358522/), it turns out that Neal faked his death and moved to France.

I'm just curious as to why he didn't inform Mozzie, or even bring him with him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, at the very end Neil fakes his death.This is to protect his loved ones.The Pink panthers wouldn't be in jail forever and it was obvious they would go after Peter or Mozzie or El at some point in time. His way of protecting them was to make the world believe Neil Caffery was dead. But this choice came with a great price, he could never be with them ever again.

Comment: But could he have not faked his death, and still informed his friends? The Panthers would have still thought he was dead.

Comment: The way I see it, the bottle of Bordeaux and the container key was a way of letting them know he is alive. The trick is ,if Mozzie believed it ,everyone would.He waited for a year to send a sign... probably waited for the heat to cool down... to let Peter know that the chase is on.
Then again this is my opinion. :)

Comment: That's a good point, and all we really have is opinion :)